# Java 7 Unicode Regex Tabs-only and Spaces-only

Tags: java, regex

I'm currently trying to add support to our application for Japanese and French language encodings. In doing so, I'm trying to create two Pattern matchers to detect tabs-only and spaces-only in a read file, regardless of language encoding.

These will be used to determine what delimiter is used in a file, so they can be processed accordingly.

When I've tried compiling a space pattern

```
Pattern.compile(" ", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
```

I don't see it generating a regex to handle different unicode space values.

eg something like `"[\\u00A0\\u2028\\u2029\\u3000\\u00C2\\u009A\\u0041]"`

Compilation seems to work properly with the  '\s' character set, but that includes tabs and newlines.

How should I be doing this in Java?

*UPDATE*

So part of the reason this wasn't working was the fact that Japanese web text HAS NO spaces, even though there appear to be spaces. Take the following line from a web imoprt:

実なので説明は不要だろう。その後1987

There are actually no spaces here う。そ. Just three characters.

Fixing this is really the subject of another question, so I have accepted Casimir's answer, as it handled the French case just fine.

Comment: I am thinking about using `\p{z}` which according to http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html represents "any kind of whitespace or invisible separator" instead of `\s`. Although I am not really sure what your problem is. What confuses me for instance is `\u00FF`. What is is doing in your regex (`ÿ` doesn't look like space or tab to me)? Also what do you mean by "In Javascript this is rather straightforward"?

Comment: Ah. \u00FF is a typo then. Sorry about that. With Javascript going to a unicode based page, opening an inspector, and doing document.body.innerText.match(/\ /g); matches all the spaces just fine. However, the same space regex in Java, even with the Pattern.compile(" ", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negated character class. Example:

```
[^\\S \\t]
```

that means `\s` without space and tab.

Or you can use a class intersection:

```
[\\s&&[^ \\t]]
```

Comment: So you would say something like: Pattern spaces = Pattern.compile("[^\\S\\t\\r\\n]", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
Pattern tabs = Pattern.compile("[^\\S \\r\\n]", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS); ?

Comment: @Gopherkhan: Yes, it is the idea.

Answer (score 1):

If I follow your question, you could use something like this for spaces -

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[ ]+$", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
String[] inputs = {" ", "  ", " \t", "Hello"};
for (String input : inputs) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    System.out.printf("For input: '%s' = %s%n", input, m.find());
}
```

Output is

```
For input: ' ' = true
For input: '  ' = true
For input: '    ' = false
For input: 'Hello' = false
```

and for tabs

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[\t]+$", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
String[] inputs = {"\t", "\t\t", " \t", "Hello"};
for (String input : inputs) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    System.out.printf("For input: '%s' = %s%n", input, m.find());
}
```

Output is

```
For input: '    ' = true
For input: '        ' = true
For input: '    ' = false
For input: 'Hello' = false
```

Finally, use `*` instead of `+` for 0 or more matches. This uses `+`, so that is 1 or more match required. Starting with (`^`) and ending with (`$`).